# Android 2.3.3 Search in AutoComplete in Hebrew does not work

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, hebrew

Hey guys I'v been searching the web to find a solution for this problem and didn't find any (I hope there's one out there)

My Problem:

I set an AutoCompleteTextView and bind it to an array with data in Hebrew

When i run the app and hit a letter in Hebrew nothing show's up, some how only when i press 'c' letter it shows my the data (in Hebrew).

Please, Any help?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Need for RTL format, Just overide the PerformFiltering method.